# Vertical Align Image Inside Div

Tags: html, css

I know there is like 100 of topics made and I've tried all 100's of them and I just can't get it to work, **Aligning the image in the middle**, if you check in to

http://one1.no-ip.org/index.php?hitta=tanto&page=search

you'll see that the logo is at the top of the screen and whatever I do I just can't make it align correctly. I'm sure something is interfering but I just can't find out what, I even made a fiddle to check if the method im using is working and it is

http://jsfiddle.net/UJATF/
*Working example with the image in the middle of the div element*

**CSS**

```
 .logo{
    background:white;
    position:absolute;

    width:105px;
    height:90px;
    line-height:90px;
    left:180px;
    margin-top:20px;

    line-height:90px;
    text-align:center;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px white,inset 0px 0px 10px -4px black;
    z-index:1000;
    overflow:hidden;    
}
.logo img{
    vertical-align:middle;
    max-width:90px;
    max-height:40px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="logo">
<a href="./index.php?page=profile&amp;id=377948"><img src="http://www.tantobil.se/images/logo.png"></a>
</div>
```

so all help would be very much appreciated

Comment: post the desired result screenshot

Comment: Also have you tried firebug or chrome developer tools as you can see exactly what is inherited and what is blocking you

Comment: where you want the logo to be placed..??

Comment: i want the image to be align in the middle like the fiddle shows, but I havent been able to achive

Comment: @pengibot Yes I've tried it and couldnt find anything that should interfere, but something still does... Haven't figured it out

Comment: If the image was in the middle wouldn't it be on top of that map? Am I missing something here? Or you want it to be right next to the location bookmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your anchor link `display : inline-block` and give to `margin-top`

as like this

```
.logo > a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 22px;
}
```

Results is

[image]

### --------

Is your are using **dynamic** with of `img` than used to this 
**Second option is**

```
.logo > a {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 105px;
}
```

Comment: the logo can Have diffrent sizes

Comment: According to logo height define to margin top

Comment: This is the same result I'm seeing anyway.

Comment: Check to my updated answer if your logo is put to the dynamic than used to this .logo > a {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 105px;
}

Comment: @RohitAzad Still curious though why the other one didnt, work on the site but worked on jsfiddle =/

Comment: table-cell is css3 properties and run to ie+8 more info http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using fixed heights in your css, why don't you just use simple math to determine the `top` position of the logo?

.content is 121px high, 
.logo is 90px high

The difference is 31px, which means you need a top offset of 15.5px
Also, set the .content to `position: relative` so you position the logo relatively to .content's top.

Comment: Cause the image can have diffrent sizes

Comment: Ah, I didn't get that because you use a fixed height on it.